# WCF fetch one data record at a time

Tags: wcf

There are many examples that use chunking and fetching a block of stream to client. I'm looking for something similar to chunching that sends one datacontract buffer at a time to client. I've seen example that is using the yiel key word to do this, but I still see the whole result returned instead. Could anyone have done this before the show me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get one record at a time, you could conceivably encode that into the contract, i.e. use pagination.

That said, I don't see much in the way of value with fetching one record at at time. You want to transmit as much as you can in a single request without opening yourself up to DOS attacks,  but there's no set value for "this much and no more" -- it's a balancing act that has no real solution.

Comment: Let says, we take away the security part of WCF. yes, I agree that we can not define what is the max block of data that balance between performance and network. In a common thought, is that true that we are gaining speed and UI response time if we send a small block of data at a time?

Comment: No. In general, it's faster to send as much data as you can at once. There may be a perceived speed increase in the UI if the user sees each individual item come up "in real time", but the overall time tends to be larger.

Comment: Great, yes you are right, the total time must be more than sending at once, it is just user feeling. thanks